# Set the plot title to wrap around and shrink the text to fit the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, title, word-wrap

```
library(ggplot2)

my_title = "This is a really long title of a plot that I want to nicely wrap \n and fit onto the plot without having to manually add the backslash n, but at the moment it does not"

r <- ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist))
r + geom_smooth() + #(left) 
opts(title = my_title)
```

can I set the plot title to wrap around and shrink the text to fit the plot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do not think there is a text wrap option in `ggplot2` (I have always just inserted \n manually).  You can, however, shrink the size of the title's text by altering your code in the following way:

```
title.size<-10
r + geom_smooth() + opts(title = my_title,plot.title=theme_text(size=title.size))
```

In fact, you all aspects of text with the `theme_text` function.

Comment: `opt` and `theme_text` have been renamed: https://github.com/wch/ggplot2/wiki/New-theme-system

Comment: UPDATE: I think in the more recent ggplot that you can add titles simply by using "\n"

Answer (score 66):

You have to manually choose the number of characters to wrap at, but the combination of `strwrap` and `paste` will do what you want.

```
wrapper <- function(x, ...) 
{
  paste(strwrap(x, ...), collapse = "\n")
}

my_title <- "This is a really long title of a plot that I want to nicely wrap and fit onto the plot without having to manually add the backslash n, but at the moment it does not"
r + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  ggtitle(wrapper(my_title, width = 20))
```

Comment: This answer by @Richie worked for me in 2018; 'labs' replacing deprecated 'opts'.  SO should let more recent and more upvoted answers (by people with x reputation score) float to the top.

Answer (score 21):

Just for an update as has been mentioned in the comments `opts` is deprecated. You need to use `labs` and you could do:

```
library(ggplot2)

my_title = "This is a really long title of a plot that I want to nicely wrap \n and fit onto the plot without having to manually add the backslash n, but at the moment it does not"
```

Option 1: Using `str_wrap` option from the `stringr` package and setting your ideal width:

```
 library(stringr)
 ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
      geom_smooth() +
      labs(title = str_wrap(my_title, 60))
```

Option 2: Using the function provided by @Richie https://stackoverflow.com/a/3935429/4767610 like this:

```
wrapper <- function(x, ...) 
{
  paste(strwrap(x, ...), collapse = "\n")
}
ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
      geom_smooth() +
      labs(title = wrapper(my_title, 60))
```

Option 3: Using the manual option (granted, this is what the OP wanted to avoid but it might be handy)

```
my_title_manual = "This is a really long title of a plot that I want to nicely wrap \n and fit onto the plot without having to manually add \n the backslash n, but at the moment it does not"

 ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
          geom_smooth() +
          labs(title = my_title_manual)
```

Option 4: Reduce the text size of the title (as in the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633773/4767610)

```
ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  labs(title = my_title) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10))
```