# Make certain facets wider without affecting others

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to tweak the code so that the facets have a minimum width allowing all text to be shown? I would not like to make the whole plot much wider as it influences the other facets too much, adding to much space. I only want to add some more white space within the three facets that have only one variable

```
ggplot(plott, aes(variable, value, fill=ID)) +  
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.50) + 
  theme_classic(base_size=6) + theme(panel.grid.major = element_line()) + 
  facet_grid(~ID, scales="free", space = "free")   + 
  labs(y="Mean abundance (%)",x="", fill="Method") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_markdown(angle=45, hjust=1),
        plot.margin = margin(l = 0 + margin_spacer(plott$value)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=0)) +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle(label = "") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=mycolors)
```

[image]

Comment: also of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654691/how-to-dynamically-wrap-facet-label-using-ggplot2