# How to center align a wrapped axis title in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a really long y-axis title with scientific notation that I want to wrap and make center aligned. I can either wrap the title and have it left aligned, or center an incorrect format of the title. How can I wrap the axis title **AND** have it centered in `ggplot2`?

Example Data

```
set.seed(321)
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 3))
colnames(df)[1:2] <- c("date","value")
df$value <- round(rnorm(3, 100,30),0)
st <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
en <- as.Date("2020-03-31")
df$date <- seq.Date(st,en,by = '1 month')
```

This makes the `ggplot2` figure with the unwrapped long y-axis title

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "",
       y = expression(paste("Here is a really really really looooonnnng title with notation (  ", m^-2,")"))) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(st, en, by = "1 month"),
               limits = c(st,en),
               date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,150),
                     breaks=seq(0,150,25)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"))
```

I have tried using `\n` which wraps the title but, the title is not centered, it is left aligned

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "",
       y = expression(paste("Here is a really really really \n looooonnnng title with notation (  ", m^-2,")"))) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(st, en, by = "1 month"),
               limits = c(st,en),
               date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,150),
                     breaks=seq(0,150,25)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"))
```

Using `str_wrap()` centers the title but the title is no longer formatted correctly

```
library(stringr)

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "",
       y = str_wrap(
         expression(paste("Here is a really really really \n looooonnnng title with notation (  ", m^-2,")")),50)
       )+
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(st, en, by = "1 month"),
               limits = c(st,en),
               date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,150),
                     breaks=seq(0,150,25)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"))
```

I tried creating a wrapper function based on [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631780/r-ggplot2-can-i-set-the-plot-title-to-wrap-around-and-shrink-the-text-to-fit-t) but it also did not format the title correctly

```
wrapper <- function(x, ...) 
{
  paste(strwrap(x, ...), collapse = "\n")
}

my_title = expression(paste("Here is a really really really looooonnnng title with notation (  ", m^-2,")"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "",
       y = wrapper(my_title, 50)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(st, en, by = "1 month"),
               limits = c(st,en),
               date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,150),
                     breaks=seq(0,150,25)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"))
```

Comment: You should be trying `axis.title.y = element_text( hjust = 0.5)` inside `theme()` (note that it is **title** not **text**) to attempt to center that text, but it still does not work when there is an `expression` in the title.

Comment: @GregorThomas adding `axis.title.y = element_text( hjust = 0.5)` to any of the example figures does not appear to do anything.

Comment: @benson23 Your answer seemed to work with some minor edits. If you place `<br>` between where the spacing got dropped and increased the `width` the answer worked. Try `y_lab <- "Here is a really really really looooonnnng<br>title with notation (m<sup> -2</sup>)"` with `width` = 12.

Comment: @tassones If my answer did provide framework for you to build on, I guess I will keep my answer here for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the package `ggtext`. If we want to use it, we need to change the normal `expression` style to HTML and CSS style (which is `<sup></sup>` for superscript).

For clearer code, I've put your y-axis title into a variable `y_lab`. The code that is doing the job is `theme(axis.title.y = element_textbox_simple(orientation = "left-rotated", halign = 0.5))`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

y_lab <- "Here is a really really really looooonnnng<br>title with notation (m<sup> -2</sup>)"
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "",
       y = y_lab)+
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(st, en, by = "1 month"),
               limits = c(st,en),
               date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,150),
                     breaks=seq(0,150,25)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_textbox_simple(orientation = "left-rotated", halign = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: @tassones See my update, you can use the `width` argument :)

Comment: On my end, when I run the above code, there is no longer a space between the words 'looooonnnng title' for the y-axis title. I have tried adjusting the `width` and it appears no matter which width I use.

Comment: @tassones Have you tried `ggtext::element_textbox_simple`?

Comment: I have tried `y_lab <- "Here is a really really really \n looooonnnng title with notation (m<sup>-2</sup>)"` with `axis.title.y = ggtext::element_textbox_simple(orientation = "left-rotated", halign = 0.5, width = unit(6, "cm"))` and also `axis.title.y = element_textbox_simple(orientation = "left-rotated", halign = 0.5, width = unit(6, "cm"))` after loading `library(ggtext)`.

Comment: @tassones Oh I think I mis-read your question. As I've said in the answer, `ggtext` only supports HTML style elements, so you need to replace `\n` with `<br>`